# In Android, what does it mean when parentheses are put between some methods?

Tags: java, android

I read some code and found something like this, see below for example.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.show();

// What is the purpose of parentheses here? Is there any benefit?
(dialog.findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(v -> Log.e(TAG, "OK"));

// instead of
dialog.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(v -> Log.e(TAG, "OK"));
```

Thank you.

Comment: No purpose. It's often fine by people that don't trust or understand the language, though. FWIW you could check for yourself by just trying both, or looking at the generated byte code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. No benefit at all. 
It may be required sometimes though. Parentheses define statements. So if you need to treat piece of your code as statement - you should use parentheses.

For example when casting type like this

```
((Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(v -> Log.e(TAG, "OK"));
```

In this case parentheses are required if you want to use some specific feature of `Button` class rather than simple `View` class which is returned from `findViewById(R.id.button)` method.

Hope it helps.